# How can I get my mouse's tilt wheel to stop sending simulated keypresses?

Tags: windows-7, scrolling, logitech-mouse

**Background:** SetPoint conflicts with some of the programs I use, so I'd like to get rid of it entirely. No, I'm not open to trying different programs.

Unfortunately, when using a Logitech MX620 mouse without SetPoint running, pressing the tilt wheel (horizontal scroll) simulates left/right keypresses rather than sending WM_MOUSEHWHEEL as expected. There are three problems with this:

- Slowly pressing right over and over again is significantly slower than native horizontal scrolling.
- It prevents me from binding the tilt wheel in games.
- It prevents programs like [WizMouse](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/) (which allow one to scroll the window currently under one's cursor rather than the active window) from carrying out core functionality.

Reverting to the default Windows mouse drivers by uninstalling SetPoint (rather than simply closing it) has no effect -- mysteriously, left/right keypresses are still sent. Programs like X-Mouse Button Control can't be used to force the correct behavior because they have no way of knowing when I'm pressing left/right on my keyboard and when my mouse is pressing them for me.

Is there anything at all I can do to get my mouse to behave properly?

Comment: What programs is SetPoint conflicting with?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it - the MX620 doesn't support on-board profiles, which allow you to customize how the mouse behaves when there are no drivers on the target system. This is a feature you find in Logitech's higher-end mice, such as the G500 and G700.

Have you used the latest version of SetPoint? I noticed they completely revamped it at least for their gaming products, where instead of three different versions of SetPoint (for my mouse, keyboard, and headset), it's all unified into a single version.